# Android SQLite REPLACE REGEX

Tags: android, regex, sqlite

I need to use REPLACE function in Android SQLite with REGEX inside:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + RCOL_2 + " FROM " + RESOURCE_TABLE + " WHERE REPLACE(LOWER(" + RCOL_2 + "), '<regex here>' , ' ') LIKE LOWER" + "('" + c + "')", null);
```

The regex i want to place here is:

```
\s{2,}
```